# Is there a way to get the value from a column at a specifc row and put it to the next row?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have Data that looks the following

```
ID    Sensor          No
1     specificSensor  1
2     1234            null 
3     1234            null
4     specificSensor  2
5     2345            null
6     2345            null
7

...
```

I need an output format like this

```
ID    Sensor          No
1     specificSensor  1
2     1234            1 
3     1234            1
4     specificSensor  2
5     2345            2
6     2345            2
7
...
```

I'm using Apache Spark in Java.

after that, the data is processed using groupby and pivot.

I'm thinking of something like

```
df.withColumn("No", functions.when(df.col("Sensor").equalTo("specificSensor"), functions.monotonically_increasing_id())
//this works as I need it
.otherwise(WHEN NULL THEN VALUE ABOVE);
```

I don't know if this is feasable in a way.

Help appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you had a grouping key, that would be easy using WindowSpec but I don't see that in the data you provided.

Comment: I am Grouping with the "No" and Pivot the Table.

what I also tried was the functions.lag() but it always crashes saying 
```Cannot evaluate expression: lag(input[3, bigint, true], 1, null)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `last` aggregation with `ignoreNulls` over an ordered window does the trick

```
df.select(
    $"ID",
    $"Sensor",
    last($"No", ignoreNulls = true) over Window.orderBy($"ID") as "No")
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------+---+
| ID|        Sensor| No|
+---+--------------+---+
|  1|specificSensor|  1|
|  2|          1234|  1|
|  3|          1234|  1|
|  4|specificSensor|  2|
|  5|          2345|  2|
|  6|          2345|  2|
+---+--------------+---+
```

P.S. I have no working Java setup right now but should be easy to translate

Comment: this is a very nice and easy solution that worked on the go!
JavaCode
boolean ignoreNulls = true;
Dataset <Row> ds1 = ds
    .withColumn("No", functions.last("No", ignoreNulls).over(Window.orderBy(ds.col("ID").as("No"))));

Answer (score 2):

Dataframe with sensor ID ranges can be created, and then joined to original dataframe:

```
val df = Seq((1, "specificSensor", Some(1)),
  (2, "1234", None),
  (3, "1234", None),
  (4, "specificSensor", Some(2)),
  (5, "2345", None),
  (6, "2345", None))
  .toDF("ID", "Sensor", "No")

val idWindow = Window.orderBy("ID")
val sensorsRange = df
    .where($"Sensor" === "specificSensor")
    .withColumn("nextId", coalesce(lead($"id", 1).over(idWindow), lit(Long.MaxValue)))

sensorsRange.show(false)

val joinColumn = $"d.ID" > $"s.id" && $"d.ID" < $"s.nextId"
val result =
  df.alias("d")
    .join(sensorsRange.alias("s"), joinColumn, "left")
    .select($"d.ID", $"d.Sensor", coalesce($"d.No", $"s.No").alias("No"))
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------+---+-------------------+
|ID |Sensor        |No |nextId             |
+---+--------------+---+-------------------+
|1  |specificSensor|1  |4                  |
|4  |specificSensor|2  |9223372036854775807|
+---+--------------+---+-------------------+


+---+--------------+---+
|ID |Sensor        |No |
+---+--------------+---+
|1  |specificSensor|1  |
|2  |1234          |1  |
|3  |1234          |1  |
|4  |specificSensor|2  |
|5  |2345          |2  |
|6  |2345          |2  |
+---+--------------+---+
```

Comment: thanks for you answer! trying to build this in java but I'm progressing really slow... is there another way to reformat?

I was thinking about: while value eq null do: copy from above

Comment: In my approach non-null values are taken from sensors. In "ollik1" approach pure Window  function is used, it is the same as "while". The only concern - Window function without partitions can has performance degradation.